# Is the MongoDB-2d-Index a Quadtree

Tags: mongodb, indexing, geospatial

It seems so to me, but I did not found an explicit approval in the documentation.

Greetings, Andre

Answer (score 0):

From the latest documentation:

> All indexes in MongoDB are B-tree indexes, which can efficiently
>   support equality matches and range queries.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-types/

For 2d and Geospatial indexes they calculate a Geohash and then index that Geohash on a btree index:

> Calculation of Geohash Values for 2d Indexes
>
> When you create a geospatial index on legacy coordinate pairs, MongoDB
>   computes geohash values for the coordinate pairs within the specified
>   location range and then indexes the geohash values.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/#geospatial-indexes-geohash